# Pass void* type to main() function

Tags: c, program-entry-point, void-pointers, argv

My main() should get an address as input which needs to be stored in `void*` address.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        HandleStr = argv[1];
        printf("\n Handle passed : %s\n",HandleStr);
    }
}
```

I want this HandleStr as type `void *`. How can I do that?

Now, I want to run the exec as `./testapp "0xaf6e9800"`

Comment: You do know that on modern operating systems processes have virtual address spaces, and more importantly each process virtual address space is separate from the other processes. Meaning that a valid address in one process will most likely not be valid in another process, and even if it's valid there's no guarantee that it points to similar data.

Comment: Arguments in `argv[]` are always strings (char*). So the addres you enter must be first converted to a number and after that treated as pointer.

Comment: If you want to share memory between two processes, there this thing called [*shared memory*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory_%28interprocess_communication%29), and even when using that the actual addresses will most likely be different in the two processes.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: The typical use-case for this is for passing the base of a shared memory space to a (non-POSIX) child process inheriting the buffer at the same offset. These sort of shenanigans are fairly common on Windows. In any event I would suggest the "%p" `printf`/`scanf` specifier here.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you want something like

```
HandleStr = (void *)strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
```

Comment: [`strtoul`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul) would probably be better. Not that it matters unless the OP is running on a system with a single unified address-space (some operating systems for small embedded systems still do that).

Answer (score 2):

If you have a C99 compiler, you should :

- decode `argv[1]` as an hexadecimal number into an `intptr_t`
- assign that value to your `void *`

Something like :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1) {
        long lh = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 16);
        if (lh != 0) {
            intptr_t ph = lh;
            void *handle = ph;
            printf("\n Handle passed : %p\n",handle);
        }
    }
}
```

But beware : **you** should know what is that value and how it should be used in your program. Because as said by Joachim Pileborg, a process cannot access any memory value.